# WP_Query is not received in Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a load more script in WordPress, everything is perfect on the homepage but there is a problem in the taxonomy page. So when you click on the category page, it pulls out all the articles. When you manually enter the category name in `$args__load['category_name']` below, everything is fine. But when you call the category of the current page with `$wp_query`, it extracts all articles.

PHP

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script('my__load__more', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/load_more.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
wp_localize_script('my__load__more', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
function my__load__more() {
    $count = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $add = $_POST['addNum'];
    $getChoose = $_POST['getChoose'];
    $count = $count + $add;
    $read = 1;

    $args__load = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    );

    global $wp_query;

    $vardi = $wp_query->query_vars;

    $args__load['category_name'] = $vardi['category_name'];

    $articles = new WP_Query( $args__load );
    $getPosts = array();
    if( $articles->have_posts() ) {
        while( $articles->have_posts() ) {
            $articles->the_post();
            if($read > $count && $read <= $count+$getChoose) {
                ob_start(); // start the buffer to capture the output of the template
                get_template_part('contents/content_general');
                $getPosts[] = ob_get_contents(); // pass the output to variable
                ob_end_clean(); // clear the buffer
                if( $read == $articles->found_posts )
                    $getPosts[] = false;
            }
            $read++;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($getPosts);
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my__load__more', 'my__load__more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my__load__more', 'my__load__more' );
?>
```

JS

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

    var addNum     = 0;
    var getChoose  = 5;
    var clicked    = false;
    var readyCount = false;

    $(".load__more__button").click(function() {
        if (!clicked) {
            $('.load__more__button').text('Loading...');
            if (readyCount == true) {
                addNum = addNum + getChoose;
            }
            readyCount = true;
            $.post(ajaxurl,
            {
                'action': 'my__load__more',
                'addNum': addNum,
                'getChoose': getChoose,
            },
            function(response) {
                var posts = JSON.parse(response);
                for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ) {
                    if( posts[i] == false )
                        $(".load__more__button").fadeOut();
                    else
                        $('.the__content.last').removeClass('last');
                    $(posts[i]).appendTo(".content__area").hide().fadeIn("slow");
                    $('.content__area').children().last().addClass('last');
                    $('.load__more__button').text('Load More');
                }
            });
            $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                clicked = false;
            });
            clicked = true;
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

But replacing this part with an existing category name, it works.

```
    global $wp_query;

    $vardi = $wp_query->query_vars;

    $args__load['category_name'] = "business"; // $vardi['category_name'];
```

I guess it doesn't see wp_query. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use `ajaxurl` when make post request - it's right way but it also mean that now `$wp_query`, in your `my__load__more()` function, work with `your.site/wp-ajax` url instead of `your.site/taxonomy`. That's why you couldn't get category name from `$wp_query->query_vars`.

**First**, I use `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my__enqueue' );` for enqueue your scripts (see example below).

**Second**, I change arguments you pass to `wp_localize_script()` function. I offer get name of category when you add script to page instead of get it inside ajax handler:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my__enqueue' );
function my__enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my__load__more', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/load_more.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

    global $wp_query;
    $vardi      = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $category   = isset( $vardi[ 'category_name' ] ) ? $vardi[ 'category_name' ] : '';

    $ajaxurl    = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

    wp_localize_script( 'my__load__more', 'my__params', array(
        'ajaxurl'   => $ajaxurl,
        'category'  => $category,
    ) );
}
```

Of course, you could add parameter `category` in same way you add `ajaxurl` in your code:

```
wp_localize_script( 'my__load__more', 'my__category', $category );
```

**Pay attention**

> If you are going to use `array` in `wp_localize_script()` function note that now you need use it in your js code as an object element, e.g., `my__params.ajaxurl` instead of `ajaxurl`

**Third**, we need to change your post call:

```js
$.post(my__params.ajaxurl, // if you use array
{
    'action': 'my__load__more',
    'addNum': addNum,
    'getChoose': getChoose,
    'category': my__params.category, // pass category to handler
}
```

**Fourth**, and last, change handler:

```php
function my__load__more(){
    // this is your handler beginning

    $args__load = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    );

    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'category' ] ) ) $args__load[ 'category_name' ] = $_POST[ 'category' ];

    $articles = new WP_Query( $args__load );
    
    // this is your handler ending
}
```

Value in `$_POST[ 'category' ]` could be empty, so we no need to use it in our query. Sure, you could add it directly to `$args__load` array with other parameters without any `if`, as you want.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks so much man! There is only one wrong part in your codes, I fixed it!

Comment: @flash, it was pleasure to help!